# Bonobo_Git_Server_WebInspector_Session_Fixation

Tags: git, session, server, web-inspector, bonobo

Bonobo Git Server version:6.5.0
My Bonobo Git Server scan an issue "Session Fixation" by WebInspect ? How do I fix it?

I have to google it, but no good resource.
I hope professional service to help me.
Is it the only way that have to change the source code to fix that?